# Reduce the number of dimensions of a Fokker Planck equation with constraint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

I have a differential equation (Fokker Planck) that takes the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = -
\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial (A_i \rho)}{\partial x_i} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^3 \frac{\partial^2 (B_{ij}\rho)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}
\end{equation}
with a constraint
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i = 1.
\end{equation}
The above differential equation is three dimensional in space $i=1,2, 3$, but along with the constraint is it possible to reduce it to two dimensions? In particular if I want to eliminate $x_3$ then what happens to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're doing from the probabilistic point of view, how does the diffusion not escape the plane $x+y+z=1$? Is it degenerate diffusion?

Comment: @Ian : to give a bit of background the Fokker-Planck comes from a master equation (Kramer Moyal expansion) and the diffusion is systematically constrained too because of this.

Comment: If the diffusion is degenerate and the drift is also suitably degenerate then you do not need to explicitly put in the constraint, $\rho$ will evolve in accordance with the constraint. But if you really want, you can always do a linear change of variable to some two-dimensional parametrization of the plane, e.g. $(x,y,z)=(x,y,1-x-y)$, and then change the equation using the chain rule. Unless you have a massive number of constraints, such a thing is probably not worth doing.

Comment: The issue mainly is that the FP I have does not admit an analytical solution and hence to solve it numerically a dimension reduction is helpful. If I understand your statement correctly then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_3} \equiv -\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}$, right?